# Create an Expression Tree that generates a parametric query for Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, expression-trees

I'm trying to create a generic class to be used to compose queries for Entity Framework (5).

I got it to work, the only problem is that the value is injected as a constant of the query instead of as a parameter. This reduces the possibilities for EF to cache the query and reuse it later on.

This is what I got so far.

```
public class MinDateFilter<T> : IFilter<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly Expression<Func<T, bool>> _predicate;

    public MinDateCandidateFilter(Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> propertySelector, DateTime from)
    {
        from = from.Date.AddDays(-1);
        from = new DateTime(from.Year, from.Month, from.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);

        Expression value = Expression.Constant(from, typeof(DateTime));
        //ParameterExpression variable = Expression.Variable(typeof(DateTime), "value");

        MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)propertySelector.Body;
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
        Expression exp = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, memberExpression.Member);

        Expression operation = Expression.GreaterThan(exp, value);
        //Expression operation = Expression.GreaterThan(exp, variable);
        _predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(operation, parameter);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Filter(IQueryable<T> items)
    {
        return items.Where(_predicate);
    }
}
```

this class can be used in two ways:

by sub-classing it:

```
public class MinCreationDateCandidateFilter : MinDateFilter<Candidate>
{
    public MinCreationDateCandidateFilter(DateTime @from) : base(c => c.CreationDate, @from) {}
}
```

or simply by instantiating it:

```
var filter = new MinDateFilter<Entities.Transition>(t => t.Date, from.Value);
```

This is what I managed to achieve so far:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
-- Other fields
FROM [dbo].[Candidates] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[CreationDate] > convert(datetime2, '1982-12-09 23:59:59.9990000', 121)
```

instead of

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
-- Other fields
FROM [dbo].[Candidates] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[CreationDate] > @p__linq__0
```

If I uncomment the two commented lines and I comment the two above, I get an error saying that the parameter "value" isn't bound.

I hope I gave all the useful details :)

Comment: Could you explain why isn't the current result good enough for your?

Comment: Because both EF and SQL can't use the first query to properly cache their output.
Of course EF will cache the compiled query but that cached item won't be usable unless the input is exactly the same.
Same happens to SQL Server that will cache the query plan specific for this value.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It seems you can't pass Expression.Constant(myValue). Using [Expression Tree Visualizer](http://exprtreevisualizer.codeplex.com/) you may find that the value is passed as MemberExpression when inspecting an actual working query, not ConstantExpression, but I still couldn't get to take a external variable and pass it with Expression.Property or alike.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When a parameter is passed as a `ConstantExpression`, like this:

```
Expression.Constant(myString)
```

... it will produce a fixed, constant symbol on the resulting query:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Bar] AS [Bar], 
FROM [dbo].[Foo] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Bar] = "Some text"
```

If you use some tool to analyze an expression like `(f => f.Bar == myString))` like I did with Expression Tree Visualizer, you see that the parameter is actually a `MemberExpression`.
So, if you want a parameter on your resulting query, you have to pass something like a property of an object, or the more convenient anonymous type:

```
Expression.Property(
    Expression.Constant(new { Value = myString }),
    "Value"
)
```

This way you're passing a property of the just-created object and your expression tree gets a `MemberExpression`, resulting in the following `CommandText`:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Bar] AS [Bar], 
FROM [dbo].[Foo] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Bar] = @p__linq__0
```